# JavaScript form fetch request submitting empty values when they are filled in

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, authentication

I am creating a Login form in JavaScript and am trying to send this form to my Ruby on Rails backend.

I have two problems:

1. When the form loads, it triggers the eventListener and sends the blank form's data to the backend. I have e.preventDefault() commented out in the second function below because I kept getting the error that it is not a function. Note: in the backend for Rails, I get the following message when I type in params. "Permitted: false" concerns me.
   `<ActionController::Parameters {"controller"=>"sessions", "action"=>"create", "session"=>{}} permitted: false>`
2. When I fill in the form with an email and password and click the submit button, the loginData (from `loginButton.addEventListener("submit", submitLogin(loginData)` submits a blank value for the email and 'password' for the password (which are the default values I set to test the values) even though these elements are filled in in the form with an actual email address and password.

Function loading login form (note: this loads just fine):

```
  // create the elements
  var div = document.createElement("div"),
    log = document.createElement("div"),
    loginForm = document.createElement("form"),

  //set form attributes
  loginForm.setAttribute("method", "POST");

  // set body styles
  document.body.style.textTransform = "capitalize";

  log.id = "login";
  log.innerHTML = "login";

  // set loginForm styles
  loginForm.id = "loginForm";

  // set the elements and styles on the form
  loginForm.innerHTML =
    "<label>username</label><br/>" +
    "<input type='text' id='login-email' value='' placeholder='email' style='" +
    inputStyles +
    "' /><br/>" +
    "<label>password</label><br/>" +
    "<input type='password' id='login-password' value='value' placeholder='*************' style='" +
    inputStyles +
    "' /><br/>" +
    "<input type='submit' id='login-button' value='Login' style='" +
    btnStyles +
    "' />" +
    "<p><a style='" +
    forgetStyles +
    "' href='#'>forget password ?</a></p><br/>";
 
  // append the buttons and form on main-div
  div.appendChild(log);
  div.appendChild(loginForm);

  // append main-div on the body
  document.body.appendChild(div);

  //get login form values to submit
  let loginEmail = document.getElementById("login-email").value;
  let loginPassword = document.getElementById("login-password").value;
  let loginData = { member: { loginEmail, loginPassword } };
}
```

SubmitLogin Function (fetch request to Rails backend):

```
async function submitLogin(e) {
  // e.preventDefault();
  const loginData = new FormData(e.target);
  debugger;
  let options = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":
        "file:///Users/awb/Coding/Flatiron/Projects/bookclub-javascript-rails-api/bookclub-frontend-javascript/index.html",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Authorization",
      Accept: "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(loginData),
  };

  fetch("http://localhost:3000/login", options)
    .then((resp) => {
      resp.json();
    })
    .then((member) => {
      console.log(member);
      return new Member(member);
    });
}
```

If it matters, this is the order of my scripts at the bottom of my index.html page:

```
    <script src="src/suggestion.js"></script>
    <script src="src/member.js"></script>
    <script src="src/gathering.js"></script>
    <script src="src/book_group.js"></script>
    <script src="src/book.js"></script>
    <script src="src/login_registration_form.js"></script>
    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
```

Where index.js calls the function "loadRegistrationLogin()" as the last line on index.js

My routes are:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :members, only [:create, :index, :show]
  resources :registrations, only: [:create]
  resources :sessions, only: [:create]
  
  post '/login', to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
  get '/logged_in', to: 'sessions#is_logged_in?'

  root to: "static#home"
  
end
```

and finally, my session controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    include CurrentMemberConcern
    skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

    def create
        member = Member
        .find_by(email: params[:member][:email])
        .try(:authenticate, params[:member][:password])

        if member 
            login!
            render json: {
                status: :created, 
                logged_in: true,
                member: member 
            }
        else 
            render json: { 
                status: 401,
             errors: ['No such member', 'Verify credentials and try again or sign up']
            }
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form is submitting automatically because of the way you've set the event handler. The `.addEventListener()` API requires a reference to a callback function as the second argument. But you passed a function call with arguments like this:

`loginButton.addEventListener("submit", submitLogin(loginData));`

You have two choices to fix this:

1. Pass a reference.

   - This will require `loginData` to be available to the handler in some other fashion.

`loginButton.addEventListener("submit", submitLogin);`

2. Enclose the call within a function expression:

`loginButton.addEventListener("submit", ()=>submitLogin(loginData));`

Option 2 is generally preferred when needing to pass parameters to the handler. But you'll see below, for you, option one is the way to go.

The leads to the next problem - `submitLogin()` function itself.

```
async function submitLogin(e) {
  // e.preventDefault();
  const loginData = new FormData(e.target);
```

In your eventListener setup you went out of your way to pass a parameter to this function - yet it isn't used. You correctly *attempt* to create a new `FormData()` Object. But interestingly enough you pass `e.target`, which is the `button` element. That won't work [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData).

To fix that change:

`const loginData = new FormData(e.target);`

to: (assuming only one form on the page)

`const loginData = new FormData(document.forms[0]);`

But we aren't done yet. Using `e.preventDefault()` is unnecessary if you set up your button correctly. A button with `type="submit"` is designed to submit the form to the server. That's also true for a button with no `type` attribute at all. You clearly don't want to submit the form, so don't put a submit button on it.

Change the login button from:

`type="submit"`

To:

`type="button"`

Now you can remove the `e` parameter from your function.

All of that should get you a lot closer to success.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! Edits I made based on the above suggestions to make this work:

Change button type from submit to type, change the event listener to: loginButton.addEventListener("click", submitLogin)

Changing the first five lines of the submitLogin function to the following:
`async function submitLogin() {
  const loginData = new FormData(document.forms[0]);
  let email = document.getElementById("login-email").value;
  let password = document.getElementById("login-password").value;
  const memberLogin = { member: { email, password } };`